# Efficient way to fill a 2d array with position based values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is the following code:

```
public int[,] GenerateArray(int size)
{
    int[,] data = new int[size, size];

    for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y)
            data[x, y] = x * y; // Example calculation function that depends on indexes

    return data;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to fill a 2d array with values. Each element's value is calculated based on it's indexes. The amount of data that needs to be processed is enourmous, so it's taking some time to deal with it. Is there a more effecient method of achieving this? Like, using a GPU shader or something.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use not array, but math function instead? If you need [2123,453] position you just calculate it's data using your func(2123,453). If you need to safe data you can safe just this modified section.

I think you can parallel calculations using GPU based Task.Run

What's the array size and calculation function?

Comment: Array is around 1048576x1048576. I do need to get all the data at once, so replacing it with calculations will not work. Calc function uses some basic math like multiplication and adding constant numbers.

Comment: I have bad news: If 1 cell is 1 byte, then this array is 1.1 TB

Comment: My bad. 1048576 is the total number of cells, so an actual array would be 1024x1024. It should be regenerated multiple times a second though, that's why I need the performance.

Comment: Why do you need that amount of data multiple times in a second? If you explain a little bit further, we could think of an alternative.

Comment: I am making a mesh that changes shape based on sound input

Comment: Use shader, it can change vertices positions